# GKE - click to deploy - prometheus-server cannot start due to `Opening storage failed open /data/XXX/meta.json: no such file or directory`

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus

I deployed prometheus + grafana using google [click-to-deploy](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google/prometheus) setup to my kubernetes cluster. Kubernetes is 1.14.10-gke.36. Unfortunately prometheus wasn't able to start - it continously starts and then gets terminated due to `Opening storage failed open /data/XXX/meta.json: no such file or directory.`
I haven't changed anything in the setup. Does anyone know how to solve this ?
My logs:

```
E 2020-05-29T14:50:09.823814201Z level=info ts=2020-05-29T14:50:09.81844866Z caller=main.go:220 msg="Starting Prometheus" version="(version=2.2.1, branch=HEAD, revision=bc6058c81272a8d938c05e75607371284236aadc)"

E 2020-05-29T14:50:09.823909260Z level=info ts=2020-05-29T14:50:09.818563567Z caller=main.go:221 build_context="(go=go1.10, user=root@149e5b3f0829, date=20180314-14:15:45)"

E 2020-05-29T14:50:09.823917570Z level=info ts=2020-05-29T14:50:09.818590869Z caller=main.go:222 host_details="(Linux 4.14.138+ #1 SMP Tue Sep 3 02:58:08 PDT 2019 x86_64 prometheus-1-prometheus-1 (none))"

E 2020-05-29T14:50:09.823924055Z level=info ts=2020-05-29T14:50:09.818612642Z caller=main.go:223 fd_limits="(soft=1048576, hard=1048576)"

E 2020-05-29T14:50:09.828319848Z level=info ts=2020-05-29T14:50:09.828105376Z caller=web.go:382 component=web msg="Start listening for connections" address=0.0.0.0:9090

E 2020-05-29T14:50:09.909997968Z level=info ts=2020-05-29T14:50:09.828059101Z caller=main.go:504 msg="Starting TSDB ..."

E 2020-05-29T14:50:09.911528108Z level=info ts=2020-05-29T14:50:09.911319586Z caller=main.go:398 msg="Stopping scrape discovery manager..."

E 2020-05-29T14:50:09.911559337Z level=info ts=2020-05-29T14:50:09.91137533Z caller=main.go:411 msg="Stopping notify discovery manager..."

E 2020-05-29T14:50:09.911600849Z level=info ts=2020-05-29T14:50:09.911396384Z caller=main.go:432 msg="Stopping scrape manager..."

E 2020-05-29T14:50:09.911611998Z level=info ts=2020-05-29T14:50:09.9114095Z caller=main.go:394 msg="Scrape discovery manager stopped"

E 2020-05-29T14:50:09.911617814Z level=info ts=2020-05-29T14:50:09.911434087Z caller=manager.go:460 component="rule manager" msg="Stopping rule manager..."

E 2020-05-29T14:50:09.911624146Z level=info ts=2020-05-29T14:50:09.911468881Z caller=manager.go:466 component="rule manager" msg="Rule manager stopped"

E 2020-05-29T14:50:09.911630066Z level=info ts=2020-05-29T14:50:09.911546355Z caller=notifier.go:512 component=notifier msg="Stopping notification manager..."

E 2020-05-29T14:50:09.911742492Z level=info ts=2020-05-29T14:50:09.911620851Z caller=main.go:407 msg="Notify discovery manager stopped"

E 2020-05-29T14:50:09.911807858Z level=info ts=2020-05-29T14:50:09.911746592Z caller=main.go:573 msg="Notifier manager stopped"

E 2020-05-29T14:50:09.911864605Z level=info ts=2020-05-29T14:50:09.91179338Z caller=main.go:426 msg="Scrape manager stopped"

E 2020-05-29T14:50:09.919909034Z level=error ts=2020-05-29T14:50:09.919646048Z caller=main.go:582 err="Opening storage failed open /data/01D37JS32JWMR54HQXBQCRJW1V/meta.json: no such file or directory"

E 2020-05-29T14:50:09.919945114Z level=info ts=2020-05-29T14:50:09.91972603Z caller=main.go:584 msg="See you next time!"
```

Comment: known issue - here's the solution https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/click-to-deploy/issues/592#issuecomment-530142191

Comment: If the solution on github fixed your issue please consider putting it as an answer. I tried to run `GKE` cluster like yours with `click-to-deploy` application and it run just fine. Could you tell more about your setup? What are the nodes specs? How many nodes is in the cluster? Did you change anything in creation process in `click-to-deploy` app?